# Get comma-separated values from jquery ajax data

Tags: jquery

I need to get a list of comma-separated values from jQuery ajax data returned from the server. The data I am getting is as below

```
<div id="1" class="clicked">A</div>
<div></div>
<div id="2" class="clicked">B</div>
<div></div>
<div id="3" class="clicked">dsf</div>
<div></div>
<div id="4" class="clicked">fd</div>
<div class=users>pp@gmail.com,pp1@gmail.com</div>
```

This is the data that I get when the alert it. I need to extract the div with class = users and update it to another div as lists. How is it possible.. Please help

Comment: did you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089015/jquery-split-function

Comment: `$('<div />').append(dataFromAjax).find('.users').text()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this works. We use `$` to cast the string into a jQuery object. Then you can use normal jQuery calls like [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get the list of emails.

Then create a list. Then append each email to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/BCmqL/3

```
//just hardcode in an example of your data
var ajaxData = '<div id="1" class="clicked">A</div><div></div><div id="2" class="clicked">B</div><div></div><div id="3" class="clicked">dsf</div><div></div><div id="4" class="clicked">fd</div><div class=users>pp@gmail.com,pp1@gmail.com</div>';

//turn it into a jQuery object, now you can just use jQuery to do stuff
$jObject = $(ajaxData);
$emails = $($jObject).filter('div.users').text();

//split the list to get all the emails
var emails = $emails.split(',');

//create a list to add list items to
var $ul = $('<ul />');

//iterate through list and append them to a ul
$(emails).each( function(index, value) {
    var $li = $('<li>'+value+'</li>');
    $ul.append($li);
});

//append new list to body
$('body').append($ul);
​
```

Comment: It worked!! Thanks.. Btw why do we need to convert it into a jquery object first. Why can't i use $(data).find('#users').text();